# Powershell CSOM to retrieve Permission levels tagged for the group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, csom

Can any one code me to retrieve the permission levels tagged for the group using Powershell CSOM.Please tell me the property 
her is my code sample

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "C:\\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"      

    #SPO Client Object Model Context 
    $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
    $spoCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName, $sPassword)   
    $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       

    $web = $spoCtx.Web
    $spGroups =$web.SiteGroups
    $spoCtx.Load($spGroups)
    $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

    foreach($group in $spGroups)
    {
        #Write-Host " Group Name = $($group.Title)"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to retrieve the Permission levels using `RoleAssignments` and `RoleDefinition` here is my code

```
Function Get-Permissions([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Object ,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleAssignmentCollection]$RoleAssignmentsCol)
{       
        $spGroups=@()
        $spoCtx = $Object

        foreach($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignmentsCol)
        {
            $RoleDefinitionBindings = $RoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings
            $RoleAssignmentMember = $RoleAssignment.Member

            $spoCtx.Load($RoleDefinitionBindings)
            $spoCtx.Load($RoleAssignmentMember)
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()


            foreach ($RoleDefinition in  $RoleDefinitionBindings)
            {
                $GroupProperty = New-Object System.Object
                $GroupProperty | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name LoginName -value $RoleAssignmentMember.LoginName
                $GroupProperty | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PrincipalType -value ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Principal]$RoleAssignmentMember).PrincipalType
                $GroupProperty | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PermissionLevel -value  $RoleDefinition.Name
                $spGroups += $GroupProperty
            }
        }

        return $spGroups
}


function GetSitePermisions
{
 try 
    {
        Add-Type -Path "D:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"   
        Add-Type -Path "D:\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"      

        $sSiteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Site Collection URL (eg: http://Server:port/Sites/Dev)" 
        $sUserName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter User Name(eg: domain\username)" 
        $sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password" -AsSecureString 

        #SPO Client Object Model Context 
        $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
        $spoCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName, $sPassword)   
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       

        $web = $spoCtx.Web
        $RoleAssignmentsCol = $web.RoleAssignments      
        $spoCtx.Load($web)

        $spoCtx.Load($RoleAssignmentsCol)
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

        $GrouppermissionLevel = @()

        Write-Host "getting Permission Level details"
        $spGroups = Get-Permissions $spoCtx $RoleAssignmentsCol

        foreach($group in $spGroups)
        {
            $GrouppermissionLevel = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                    GroupName = $group.LoginName
                                    PrincipalType= $group.PrincipalType
                                    PermissionLevel = $group.PermissionLevel
                                    } | Select  GroupName,PrincipalType,PermissionLevel

            $GrouppermissionLevel| Export-CSV ("D:\GroupPermissionLevel.csv") -NoTypeInformation -Append  
        }
    } 
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
    }  
}

GetSitePermisions ;
```